# OpenCV Pixel with "no value"

Tags: opencv

Is it possible in OpenCV to have pixels with no colour? Like a transparent layer or in gimp if you delete all colours or elements on a layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can using **BGRA** system by making the alpha value equal to `0`.

Example:

```
cv::Mat img(ROW, COLS, CV_8UC4, cv::Scalar(B_VALUE,G_VALUE,R_VALUE,0 /* This is the alpha*/));
```

Now all the this `cv::Mat` pixels are 100% transparent. You can change the alpha value to 255 so it is fully opaque or any value in the range `[0,255]` for a degree of transparent.